# error TS6059: /interfaces/ICard.ts' is not under 'rootDir'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

My project structure is as below:

```
Some ASP.NET Dir
-projects/lib1
         /lib2
-src (Angular app)
-package.json
-angular.json

In lib2:
  /src
       -lib
          -interfaces
                     -ICard.ts
          -services
          -ui-components
                       -card
                            -card.component.ts
           ui-components.module.ts
           package.json (UI component's)
           public_api.ts (UI component's)

   public-api.ts
   package.json
   tsconfig.lib.json
```

src's public_api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/lib.service';
export * from './lib/lib.component';
export * from './lib/lib.module';
export { ICard } from './lib/interfaces/ICard';
```

In card.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ICard } from '../../interfaces/ICard';
import { CommonHelperService } from '../../services/common-helper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() Card: ICard;
  constructor(private commonHelper: CommonHelperService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Card = this.commonHelper.DefaultCardFallback;
  }
}
```

In tsconfig.lib.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am getting this error when I build this lib:

error TS6059: File 'ASP.NET/projects/lib/src/lib/interfaces/ICard.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'ASP.NET\projects\lib\src\lib\ui-components'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

Why does the typescript not include the interface? What should be the right way for the interface exports?